# How to make it responsive using css

Tags: css

[image: icon]

Below code is my css and i'm trying to add an icon using another css but the icon css is not responsive how can i make it responsive.

```
.iconbox-singleD1 {
    background: rgba(160, 215, 231, 0.85);
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px rgba(74, 141, 245, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px rgba(74, 141, 245, 0.2);
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 24px;
}
.iconbox-singleD1.active:before{
    opacity:1;
}
.iconbox-singleD1:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 21px;
    right: 21px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
    background: rgb(209 243 253 / 85%);
    /* opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s; */
    transition: opacity .25s;
}
.iconbox-singleD1.iconbox-singl {
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: #FFFFFF;    
}

.iconbox-singleD1 .box-title {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.iconbox-singleD1 p {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    /* text-transform: uppercase; */
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    /* color: #0d1f3c; */
    color: #fff;
}
.iconbox-singleN1 h5 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #0d1f3c;
}
```

And this is the html skeleton. Here I'm using another css for icon div tag how can i combine with the above css to make it responsive.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="iconbox-singleD1">
            <div class="box-title">
              <div>
                <p>New Patients</p>
                <h5 class="Dashboard-header-color">{{todaysAppointment}}</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="padLeftIcon">
                <mat-icon>hotel</mat-icon>
              </div>
            </div>       
          </div>
        </div>
```

and this is the css i use in icon div tag

```
.padLeftIcon{
    position: absolute;
    left: 173px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `font-size` in `em` e.g. `font-size: 1.2em;`

Working example link: https://jsfiddle.net/waqasahmad724/1ybxtp39/2/

Comment: can you give me a working css

Comment: I'm talking about using my above css. I'm using absolute for positioning my icon so there comes an issue.

Comment: At the above html code i'm using two div tag and i want to put the icon div tag at the right side according to the above image. Issue comes here when the windows resize icon tag goes outside the above image div tag. What i want is that i want it stay inside the div tag at the same position.

Comment: @SanamahiChannel here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/waqasahmad724/1ybxtp39/2/